# title is stuck with everything in the center of the screen

Tags: php, html, css

So I would like to move up the big title a little bit so i leave space in the main page and css isn't helping i tried many methods like position:absolute , position:relative , position:fixed etc.. still nothing happens

**html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>AGENCE DE VOYAGES</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<center>
<body background="ny.jpg" size="100%" width="100%" height="100%" align="center">
<header>
<div class="main">
<div class="logo">
<img src="logo.png">
</div>
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="acceuil.php" class="btn">Accueil</a></li>
<li><a href="services.php" class="btn">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="clients.php" class="btn">Clients</a></li>
<li><a href="apropos.php" class="btn">A Propos</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.php" class="btn">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="title">
<h1 color="white">AGENCE DE VOYAGES</h1>
</div>
<div class="login">
<center>
<form action="auth.php" method="post">
<fieldset style="width:500px;">
<legend align='center'><h1>Connexion</h1></legend>
<table>
<tr>
<td><b>Email: </b></td>
<td><input type="email" name="email"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Mot de passe: </b></td>
<td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
</tr>
</div>
</table>
</fieldset>
</form>
<div class="button">
<a href="login.php" class="btn">S'AUTHENTIFIER</a>
<a href="signup.php" class="btn">S'INSCRIRE</a>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You start `<center>` before the `<body>` but close it after `</body>`. `<background>` attribute is obsolete, not sure if the `size` attribute ever existed, use CSS to style it instead. You never seem to close your `<header>`. Proper code indentation would be nice

Comment: thx, still unable to move up the title tho ..

Comment: plug your html into https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea and fix the errors. Then experiment with css to style.

Comment: @kerbh0lz size attribute still exist but its ancient from HTML4. The entire site is ancient tbh as noone uses tables to layout a design anymore.

Comment: @tacoshy Thx, are you sure though, https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.1 doesn't mention it

Comment: @kerbh0lz yes I'm sure. Just search for size attribute on SO. You find questions about it already befor 2012 (public release of HTML5)

Answer (score 0):

I have left you an example of what you can do to move your text with css or make it smaller, hope that will solve your problem. I only added to your `<h1>` tag the class title like so:

`<h1 class="title" color="white">AGENCE DE VOYAGES</h1>`

```css
.title{
  font-size: 20px;  /*You can choose here the size of your text*/
  float: left; /*Or use right instead of left its up to you*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>AGENCE DE VOYAGES</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<center>
<body background="ny.jpg" size="100%" width="100%" height="100%" align="center">
<header>
<div class="main">
<div class="logo">
<img src="logo.png">
</div>
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="acceuil.php" class="btn">Accueil</a></li>
<li><a href="services.php" class="btn">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="clients.php" class="btn">Clients</a></li>
<li><a href="apropos.php" class="btn">A Propos</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.php" class="btn">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="title">
<h1 class="title" color="white">AGENCE DE VOYAGES</h1>
</div>
<div class="login">
<center>
<form action="auth.php" method="post">
<fieldset style="width:500px;">
<legend align='center'><h1>Connexion</h1></legend>
<table>
<tr>
<td><b>Email: </b></td>
<td><input type="email" name="email"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Mot de passe: </b></td>
<td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
</tr>
</div>
</table>
</fieldset>
</form>
<div class="button">
<a href="login.php" class="btn">S'AUTHENTIFIER</a>
<a href="signup.php" class="btn">S'INSCRIRE</a>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```